# Localhost is not responding giving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, localhost, port

I am working on my Final Year project. Last day the localhost was working fine. I have seen my app running for several times by this configuration but now the localhost is not responding its giving the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the browser. I dont know what have happened I've changed the port from :3000 to :8080 but it didn't work. The last time I close the terminal directly without closing the localhost server by using ctrl+ c. I am newb and dont getting what is the actual issue and how to fix it. help plz

I am using the mongodb and webpack as well

here is the config file

```
const config = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
  jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "YOUR_secret_key",
  mongoUri: process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGO_HOST ||
    'mongodb://' + (process.env.IP || 'localhost') + ':' +
    (process.env.MONGO_PORT || '27017') +
    '/professionalservices',
  stripe_connect_test_client_id: 'YOUR_stripe_connect_test_client',
  stripe_test_secret_key: 'YOUR_stripe_test_secret_key',
  stripe_test_api_key: 'YOUR_stripe_test_api_key'
}

export default config
```

Comment: please add some more code

Comment: @Alex as i told earlier nothing has changed in the config's files as the app was running previously. The error behind i think is that i closed the cmd.exe window without closing the local server last time .. that is causing the connection error in the browser.

Comment: could you suggest something to this reason please?

Comment: if you close your terminal did you check your previous port is running or not, for check run localhost:3000

Comment: it's showing the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when i close the new server in terminal and try to access the previous if any ..

Comment: previous port is not running

Comment: ok than you have to kill running port using

Comment: netstat -ano | findstr :3000

Comment: taskkill /PID <typeyourPIDhere> /F

Comment: See also this one netstat -tnl | grep 8080

Comment: netstat -ano | findstr :3000 is showing nothing(Not showing any PID) moreover i have run the resmon.exe and found node is not running on any of the PID

Comment: I have run the previous version of project.. and its running ..